# Snake Game issues, snake does not move

Tags: java

I am trying to recreate a simple snake game for my programming class. I am using java on the program Eclipse. In case you didn't know how to work this game, it is a game where when the snake eats the dot, it grows and  the game is over when the snake hits itself. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
 import java.awt.Color; 
 import java.awt.Dimension;  
 import java.awt.Graphics;  
 import java.awt.Point;  
 import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;  
 import java.awt.event.KeyListener;  
 import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;  
 import java.util.LinkedList;  
 import java.util.Random;  
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Source extends JFrame implements Runnable, KeyListener {
private final int boxHeight = 15; //each individual box height
private final int boxWidth = 15; //each individual box width
private final int gridWidth = 25; //Total width of all boxes in Grid
private final int gridHeight = 25; //Total height of all boxes in Grid
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
private LinkedList<Point> snake;
public Point fruit;
public int direction = Direction.noDirection;
private Thread runThread;
private Graphics globalGraphics;
private int score = 0;


public void paint (Graphics g)
{
    setBounds(0,0,500,500);
    snake = new LinkedList<Point>();
    GenerateDefaultSnake();
    PlaceFruit();
    globalGraphics = g.create();
    this.addKeyListener(this);
    if (runThread == null){
        runThread = new Thread(this);
        runThread.start();
    }
}
public void GenerateDefaultSnake(){

    score = 0;
    snake.clear();
    snake.add(new Point (0,2));
    snake.add(new Point (0,1));
    snake.add(new Point (0,0));
    direction = Direction.noDirection;
}

public void Draw (Graphics g){ //main method of what will be drawn
    g.clearRect(0, 0, boxWidth * gridWidth + 10, boxHeight * gridHeight +20);
    //create a new image
    BufferedImage buffer = new BufferedImage(boxWidth * gridWidth + 10, boxHeight * gridHeight +20, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics bufferGraphics = buffer.getGraphics();

    DrawFruit(bufferGraphics);  
    DrawGrid(bufferGraphics);
    DrawSnake(bufferGraphics);
    DrawScore(bufferGraphics);


    //flip
    g.drawImage(buffer, 0,0, boxWidth * gridWidth +10, boxHeight * gridHeight +20, this);

}
public void Move(){ //directions
    Point head = snake.peekFirst(); //head of snake, allows us to have body follow in chronological order
    Point newPoint = head;

    snake.remove(snake.peekLast()); //removes end of tail
    if(newPoint.equals(fruit))
    {
        score += 10;
        Point addPoint = (Point) newPoint.clone();
        //the snake has hit the fruit
        switch(direction){
        case Direction.North:
            newPoint = new Point (head.x, head.y -1);
            break;
        case Direction.South:
            newPoint = new Point(head.x,head.y +1);
            break;
        case Direction.West:
            newPoint = new Point(head.x -1,head.y);
            break;
        case Direction.East:
            newPoint = new Point(head.x + 1,head.y);
            break;
        }
        snake.push(addPoint);
        PlaceFruit();
    }
    else if (newPoint.x < 0 || newPoint.x > (gridWidth - 1)){
        //we went out of bounds, reset game
        GenerateDefaultSnake();
        return;
    }
    else if (newPoint.y < 0 || newPoint.y > (gridHeight - 1 )){
        //we went out of bounds, reset game
        GenerateDefaultSnake();
        return;
    }
    else if (snake.contains(newPoint)){
        //we ran into ourselves, reset game

        GenerateDefaultSnake();
        return;
    }
    //if we reach this point of the game, we are still good 
    snake.push(newPoint); //pushes all points one point ahead when you eat fruit and adds fruit that you ate at the end
}

public void DrawScore(Graphics g){
    g.drawString("Score: " + score,0, boxHeight * gridHeight +10);
}
public void DrawGrid (Graphics g){
    //drawing outer rectangle
    g.drawRect(0,0, gridWidth * boxWidth, gridHeight * boxHeight); //creates the outer rectangle
    //drawing vertical lines of grid
    for (int x = boxWidth; x < gridWidth * boxWidth; x += boxWidth){
        g.drawLine(x, 0, x, boxHeight * gridHeight);
    }
    //drawing horizontal lines of grid
    for(int y = boxHeight; y < gridHeight * boxHeight; y += boxHeight){
        g.drawLine(0, y, gridWidth * boxWidth, y);
    }
}
public void DrawSnake(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    for ( Point p : snake){
        g.fillRect(p.x * boxWidth,  p.y * boxHeight,  boxWidth,  boxHeight);
    }
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}
public void DrawFruit(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(fruit.x * boxWidth, fruit.y * boxHeight, boxWidth, boxHeight);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}
public void PlaceFruit()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomX = rand.nextInt(gridWidth);
    int randomY = rand.nextInt(gridHeight);
    Point randomPoint = new Point(randomX, randomY);
    while (snake.contains(randomPoint)){
        randomX = rand.nextInt(gridWidth);
        randomY = rand.nextInt(gridHeight);
        randomPoint = new Point(randomX, randomY);
    }
    fruit = randomPoint;

}
public void run() {
    while(true){
        //runs indefinitely, every second the objects in this loop will move
        Move();
        Draw(globalGraphics);
        try{
            Thread.currentThread();
            Thread.sleep(100); //game will be updating itself every tenth of a second (.1 of a second)
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    switch (e.getKeyCode())
    {
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
        if(direction != Direction.South)
            direction = Direction.North;
            break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
        if(direction != Direction.North)
        direction = Direction.South;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
        if(direction != Direction.West)
        direction = Direction.East;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
        if(direction != Direction.East)
        direction = Direction.West;
        break;
    }
}
    public class Direction {
public static final int noDirection = 0;
public static final int North = 1;
public static final int South = 2;
public static final int West = 3;
public static final int East = 4;
   }
    public class Snake extends JFrame{



    c = new Source();
    c.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (640,480));
    c.setVisible(true);
    c.setFocusable(true);
    }
  @Override
  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
  @Override
   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
     }
  }*
```

Comment: Which part of the code is supposed to make the snake move?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how are you launching this (so I can test the same way you are).

Comment: The public void Move() part of the code is supposed to make the snake move. I think the problem is there @CodeCamper

Comment: @user3542369 would you mind editing your original post instead of putting the code in the comments?

Comment: I am running this on Eclipse @user3507600

Comment: Ok I will do that now. Sorry for the confusion @user3507600

Comment: Have you tried plaguing your code with print statements and/or using the debugger yet?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your `move()` method, you always fail in the last case(`else if (snake.contains(newPoint))`), because the new point you've created is always inside of your current snake.

I'm working on a solution for you.

**EDIT:**

This section is wrong:

```
if(newPoint.equals(fruit))
{
    score += 10;
    Point addPoint = (Point) newPoint.clone();
    //the snake has hit the fruit
    switch(direction){
    case Direction.North:
        newPoint = new Point (head.x, head.y -1);
        break;
    case Direction.South:
        newPoint = new Point(head.x,head.y +1);
        break;
    case Direction.West:
        newPoint = new Point(head.x -1,head.y);
        break;
    case Direction.East:
        newPoint = new Point(head.x + 1,head.y);
        break;
    }
    snake.push(addPoint);
    PlaceFruit();
}
```

**EDIT 2:**  Brainless Box is right that the points and addPoint should be in the check for hitting the fruit.  I also added some logic to handle the fruit a bit better.

```
public void Move(){ //directions

    Point head = snake.peekFirst(); //head of snake, allows us to have body follow in chronological order
    Point newPoint = head;

    snake.remove(snake.peekLast()); //removes end of tail


    Point addPoint = (Point) newPoint.clone();
    switch(direction) {
    case Direction.North:
        newPoint = new Point (head.x, head.y -1);
        break;
    case Direction.South:
        newPoint = new Point(head.x,head.y +1);
        break;
    case Direction.West:
        newPoint = new Point(head.x -1,head.y);
        break;
    case Direction.East:
        newPoint = new Point(head.x + 1,head.y);
        break;
    }

    //the snake has hit the fruit
    if(newPoint.equals(fruit))
    {
        score += 10;
        fruit = null;
        snake.push(addPoint);
    }
    else if (newPoint.x < 0 || newPoint.x > (gridWidth - 1)){
        //we went out of bounds, reset game
        GenerateDefaultSnake();
        return;
    }
    else if (newPoint.y < 0 || newPoint.y > (gridHeight - 1 )){
        //we went out of bounds, reset game
        GenerateDefaultSnake();
        return;
    }
    else if (snake.contains(newPoint)){
        //we ran into ourselves, reset game
        GenerateDefaultSnake();
        return;
    }

    //if we reach this point of the game, we are still good 
    PlaceFruit();
    snake.push(newPoint); //pushes all points one point ahead when you eat fruit and adds fruit that you ate at the end
}
```

In addition to that, add `if (fruit != null) return;` as the first line of your `PlaceFruit()` method.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I changed the code, but it still looks like the snake is not moving. Any suggestions? @user3507600

Comment: @user3542369 I assume you pressed a button, yes?  Since you do not specify a starting direction, it won't move until you press an arrow key.

Comment: Something has happened. When I started to play the game, I saw that sometimes the dot does not show up in the middle of the game. I am guessing it is because the dot relocates to somewhere where the snake is already, therefore the snake "eats" it before it can actually be seen. Another dot does not appear and then we are left with just the snake. Any solutions? I think it is a problem with the PlaceFruit() method. @user3507600

Comment: @user3542369, that doesn't sounds correct, the while loop you have in the `PlaceFruit()` method should prevent that.  Is it possible that part of your play area is not being displayed?  I've noticed that when I run the game there appears to be about 1 rows and 2 columns that are not displayed.

Comment: I have been trying to fix the window so that the whole play area could be displayed but I couldn't seem to find out a solution. Any help with that? @user3507600

Comment: @user3542369 you can either use `this.setUndecorated(true);` which will remove your borders and title bar (which is what the board is hiding under); or you can add some amount to every one of your graphics draw functions (you need to add about 5 to every x value (X NOT WIDTH) and about 20 to every y value (Y NOT HEIGHT)).

Answer (score 0):

The code for getting your snake to move is slightly incorrect.  You should always move, and only add the score and re-create a fruit if the snake runs into it.  See below:

```
public void Move(){ //directions

    Point head = snake.peekFirst(); //head of snake, allows us to have body follow in chronological order
    Point newPoint = head;

    snake.remove(snake.peekLast()); //removes end of tail


    Point addPoint = (Point) newPoint.clone();
    switch(direction) {
    case Direction.North:
        newPoint = new Point (head.x, head.y -1);
        break;
    case Direction.South:
        newPoint = new Point(head.x,head.y +1);
        break;
    case Direction.West:
        newPoint = new Point(head.x -1,head.y);
        break;
    case Direction.East:
        newPoint = new Point(head.x + 1,head.y);
        break;
    }

    //the snake has hit the fruit
    if(newPoint.equals(fruit))
    {
        score += 10;
        snake.push(addPoint);
        PlaceFruit();
    }
    else if (newPoint.x < 0 || newPoint.x > (gridWidth - 1)){
        //we went out of bounds, reset game
        GenerateDefaultSnake();
        PlaceFruit();
        return;
    }
    else if (newPoint.y < 0 || newPoint.y > (gridHeight - 1 )){
        //we went out of bounds, reset game
        GenerateDefaultSnake();
        PlaceFruit();
        return;
    }
    else if (snake.contains(newPoint)){
        //we ran into ourselves, reset game
        GenerateDefaultSnake();
        PlaceFruit();
        return;
    }

    //if we reach this point of the game, we are still good 
    snake.push(newPoint); //pushes all points one point ahead when you eat fruit and adds fruit that you ate at the end
}
```

Comment: The snake moves now! Except now, once it eats the fruit, no other fruit appears

Comment: There's an issue where if you run into yourself or the walls of the game, another fruit won't appear.  The edit I just made corrects that; however, the fruit will bounce around until the player starts moving because he's constantly "running into himself".  Fix that one, and you should be good to go!

Comment: Please consider accepting one of the answers here to remove a question from the unanswered list.